# Most isolated place on Earth

Tags: knowledge, geography

If you come to this place on Earth then at certain times the closest people to you are in Space! Where are you?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> [Point Nemo](https://oceanservice.noaa.gov/facts/nemo.html), a point in the ocean between New Zealand and Chile (rectilinear, not great circle) defined as being furthest from land.

IIS Orbital path:
[image: IIS Orbital path]

> As we can see, the IIS is at an inclination to reach the latitude of Point Nemo, and at an orbital altitude of roughly 400km should at times be significantly closer than anyone on land.

Sadly, I cannot confirm a lack of international shipping in the area, nor military vessels, but the claim that at one point the nearest human was in space seems plausible.

Comment: You got it! Well done.